# Flex Builder 3: Debugger traces error, when fixing the as file, keeps throwing same error, stuck in past

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flexbuilder

I'm running my first project that I'm compiling with flex builder. Before I used to compile with flash or flash develop.

For a while it worked pretty neatly. But as soon as it start throwing typeerrors, I can't seem to compile the updated and saved actionscript files. It seems as if it keeps stuck in time and compiles the actionscript file from when the error was still there.

Perhaps any options I missed regarding configuring the debugger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing a Clean?  In FlexBuilder, the Project menu, select Clean...

It's possible Flex is building off of temp files, in which case doing a clean should clear them out.

Comment: ok, it fixes the problem, but is there a work around for it, to clean up every time something goes wrong is a bit annoying

Comment: I've never seen this happen, so I'm guessing something else is going on on your system that's causing Flex to think it doesn't need to recompile the changed files.

Answer (score 0):

Minimize Eclipse and see if any other windows are lurking behind the IDE, also try terminating all sessions, and like Herms suggested go to Project->Clean...->YourProject

I'm sure Chris already moved on since '08 but for anyone else this solved the problem for me.